# How to update the already installed nodejs in ubuntu

Tags: node.js

If i update the old version that not updated  only displayed my current version( v0.10.37). so tell me how to update the version of nodejs in ubuntu.

Comment: Look for `nvm`, it is a great tool to install multiple versions of NodeJS on a single machine. https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of options here. There's a tool called nvm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

I haven't tried this yet so no opinion on it either way.

**Or**

You can do it via the n package for npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

Ensure you have everything backed up and can roll back if you get funny behaviour!

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

The last line can also be

```
sudo n <desired version>
```

I have done this with success